# Efficient bin-assignment in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, binning, set-operations

i have a very large 1D python array `x` of somewhat repeating numbers and along with it some data `d` of the same size.

```
x = np.array([48531, 62312, 23345, 62312, 1567, ..., 23345, 23345])
d = np.array([0    , 1    , 2    , 3    , 4   , ..., 99998, 99999])
```

in my context "very large" refers to 10k...100k entries. Some of them are repeating so the number of unique entries is about 5k...15k.

I would like to group them into the bins. This should be done by creating two objects. One is a matrix buffer, `b` of data items taken from d. The other object is a vector `v` of unique x values each of the buffer columns refers to. Here's the example:

```
v =  [48531, 62312, 23345, 1567, ...]
b = [[0    , 1    , 2    , 4   , ...]
     [X    , 3    , ....., ...., ...]
     [ ...., ....., ....., ...., ...]
     [X    , X    , 99998, X   , ...]
     [X    , X    , 99999, X   , ...] ]
```

Since the numbers of occurrences of each unique number in x vary some of the values in the buffer b are invalid (indicated by the capital `X`, i.e. "don't care").

---

It's very easy to derive v in numpy:

```
v, n = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)  # yay, just 5ms
```

and we even get `n` which is the number of valid entries within each column in b. Moreover, `(np.max(n), v.shape[0])` returns the shape of the matrix b that needs to be allocated.

But **how to efficiently generate b**?
A for-loop could help

```
b = np.zeros((np.max(n), v.shape[0]))
for i in range(v.shape[0]):
    idx = np.flatnonzero(x == v[i])
    b[0:n[i], i] = d[idx]
```

This loop iterates over all columns of b and extracts the indices `idx`by identifying all the locations where `x == v`.

However I don't like the solution because of the rather slow for loop (taking about 50x longer than the unique command). I'd rather have the operation vectorized.

---

So one vectorized approach would be to create a matrix of indices where `x == v` and then run the `nonzero()` command on it along the columns. however, this matrix would require memory in the range of 150k x 15k, so about 8GB on a 32 bit system.

To me it sounds rather silly that the `np.unique`-operation can even efficiently return the inverted indices so that `x = v[inv_indices]` but that there is no way to get the v-to-x assignment lists for each bin in v. This should come almost for free when the function is scanning through x. Implementation-wise the only challenge would be the unknown size of the resulting index-matrix.

---

Another way of phrasing this problem assuming that the np.unique-command is the method-to-use for binning:

given the three arrays `x, v, inv_indices` where `v` are the unique elements in `x` and `x = v[inv_indices]` is there an efficient way of generating the index vectors `v_to_x[i]` such that `all(v[i] == x[v_to_x[i]])` for all bins `i`?

I shouldn't have to spend more time than for the np.unique-command itself. And I'm happy to provide an upper bound for the number of items in each bin (say e.g. 50).

Comment: Does `itertools.groupby` help? I'm not sure what you're looking for...

Comment: If you define in Pandas  your numpy arrays as `df = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "d": d})`, then you can collate the data for each unique value with `unik = df.groupby(["x"])["d"].unique().reset_index()`. This is not an array, like you want, but a column contains numpy arrays of all d values for each unique x value. Idk, what you want to do next with your data, but maybe you don't need a full b array with all those NaN values.

Comment: @user202729 I looked into this groupby-bussines and the problem seems to be that groupby only groups the values itself, not their indices in the list so if you invoke `for key,value in groupby(x)` you can turn the group into a list `l = list(value)`. This will leave you with `True == (li == key) for all li in l`. I would need the indices, i.e. ` True == (x[li] == key) for all li in l`

Comment: What about `enumerate`?

Comment: @Piinthesky even though your suggestion works the grouping command `unik = df.groupby(["x"])["d"].unique().reset_index()` takes ~900msec to compute for the kind of problems described above. This is not an option unless it can somehow be sped up.

Comment: @Piinthesky Only if it gets heavily rewritten. As is, the question is off-topic there. See https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users. It's perfectly fine here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received the answer I was looking for by rephrasing the question, see here: [python: vectorized cumulative counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48690864/python-vectorized-cumulative-counting)

by "cumulative counting" the `inv_indices` returned by `np.unique()` we receive the array indices of the sparse matrix so that

```
c = cumcount(inv_indices)
b[inv_indices, c] = d
```

cumulative counting as proposed in the thread linked above is very efficient. Run times lower than 20ms are very realistic.

Answer (score 0):

based on the suggestion from @user202729 I wrote this code

```
x_sorted_args = np.argsort(x)
x_sorted = x[x_sorted_args]

i = 0
v = -np.ones(T)
b = np.zeros((K, T))

for k,g in groupby(enumerate(x_sorted), lambda tup: tup[1]):
    groups = np.array(list(g))[:,0]
    size = groups.shape[0]

    v[i] = k
    b[0:size, i] = d[x_sorted_args[groups]]
    i += 1
```

in runs in about ~100ms which results in some considerable speedup w.r.t. the original code posted above.

It first enumerates the values in `x` adding the corresponding index information. Then the enumeration is grouped by the actual `x` value which in fact is the second value of the tuple generated by `enumerate()`.

The for loop iterates over all the groups turning those iterators of tuples `g` into the `groups` matrix of size `(size x 2)` and then throws away the second column, i.e. the `x` values keeping only the indices. This leads to `groups` being just a 1D array.

`groupby()` only works on sorted arrays.

---

Good work. I'm just wondering if we can do even better? Still a lot of unreasonable data copying seems to happen. Creating a list of tuples and then turning this into a 2D matrix just to throw away half of it still feels a bit suboptimal.